# AWS Elastic Beanstock. rails cannot connect to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I cannot solve this issue, mysql will not connect. using eb deploy. And I am using Ruby v 2.3.1

```
 + su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
  rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'labr.cyp2t1256323.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
  (See full trace by running task with --trace) (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir
```

Database.yml

```
  production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    reconnect: false
    pool: 20
    database: ***
    username: *****
    password: *****
    host: labr.cyp2t1256323.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    port: 3306
```

3306 is enabled on Amazon EC2 console, rails-env is at health red

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add a new security group that accept all traffic. And add your db instance to this group.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html